# How to load entity inside another entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem joining tables to retrieve information

I have three tables:

1. `city` (city_id, name) - information about the city.
2. `state` (state_id, name) - information about state
3. `city_state_map` (city_id, state_id)

and I have two hibernate entities: `City`, `State`.

I want to load `State` from `City` entity to get the `State` of the `City`.

I have no idea how to do it for three tables. I got many tutorials that showed how to join two tables.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `@ManyToOne` mapping. For example:

```
@ManyToOne
private State state;
```

(by default hibernate's naming strategy will look for `state_id`. Otherwise you may need to specify `@JoinColumn`)

Comment: Sounds to me as if he is after eager loading.

Comment: my question was: how to join three tables? how are you going to specify the table name which will be used for joiniing?

Comment: using `@JoinTable`. But you didn't mention you need `@ManyToMany`, and it seems you need `@ManyToOne`